# Arduino yun pip install mysql-python failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino-yun

I use pip install mysql-python  it show me

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
>
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-r4ybCJ/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
>
>     metadata, options = get_config()
>
>   File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
>
>     libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
>
>   File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
>
>     raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
>
> EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
> ```

I searched on google lots way say need  pip install libmysqlclient-dev or python-dev I tried them both but still not work
Hope anyone can help me !

Comment: You are running this on an Arduino?

Comment: yes i used putty to run it